# QueryDSL with MongoDB can't serialize property from type Long to String when filtering using stringValue() or like()

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I'm trying to query / filter some simple data using QueryDSL, MongoDB and Spring Data.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.M4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document
public class Library {

  private Address address;

  @NotNull
  private Long books = 4L;

  ...

}
```

My first approach:

```
public Page<Library> findAll(Predicate predicate, MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters) {
    final QLibrary qLibrary = QLibrary.library;
    final BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

    if (parameters.containsKey("booksCount")) {
      builder.and(qLibrary.booksCount.stringValue().startsWith(parameters.getFirst("booksCount")));
    }

    final BooleanExpression expression = (BooleanExpression) predicate;
    return repository.findAll(expression.and(builder.getValue()), Pageable.unpaged());
}
```

My second approach:

```
public class LibraryBindings implements QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QLibrary> {

    @Override
    public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QLibrary root) {
        bindings.bind(root.booksCount).first(new SingleValueBinding<NumberPath<Long>, Long>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate bind(NumberPath<Long> path, Long value) {
                return path.stringValue().startsWith(value.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My third approach:

```
public class LibraryBindings implements QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QLibrary> {

    @Override
    public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QLibrary root) {
        bindings.bind(root.booksCount).first(new SingleValueBinding<NumberPath<Long>, Long>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate bind(NumberPath<Long> path, Long value) {
                return path.like(value.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Using approaches above I get an exception:

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Illegal operation str(library.booksCount)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.visit(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:323) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.visit(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:54) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at com.querydsl.core.types.OperationImpl.accept(OperationImpl.java:83) ~[querydsl-core-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.asDBValue(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:146) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.asDBKey(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:138) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SpringDataMongodbSerializer.asDBKey(SpringDataMongodbSerializer.java:158) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.visit(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:227) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.visit(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:54) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at com.querydsl.core.types.OperationImpl.accept(OperationImpl.java:83) ~[querydsl-core-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.handle(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:58) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.visit(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:185) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.visit(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:54) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at com.querydsl.core.types.OperationImpl.accept(OperationImpl.java:83) ~[querydsl-core-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.handle(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:58) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongodbDocumentSerializer.toQuery(MongodbDocumentSerializer.java:69) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QuerydslAbstractMongodbQuery.createQuery(QuerydslAbstractMongodbQuery.java:166) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QuerydslFetchableMongodbQuery.createQuery(QuerydslFetchableMongodbQuery.java:197) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QuerydslFetchableMongodbQuery.createQuery(QuerydslFetchableMongodbQuery.java:190) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QuerydslFetchableMongodbQuery.fetch(QuerydslFetchableMongodbQuery.java:111) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SpringDataMongodbQuery.fetch(SpringDataMongodbQuery.java:28) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.QuerydslMongoPredicateExecutor.findAll(QuerydslMongoPredicateExecutor.java:160) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar:2.2.0.M4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.M2.jar:5.2.0.M2]
```

All other filters / queries are working properly (comparing strings, comparing numbers to numbers or booleans to booleans and so on). QueryDSL is configured properly.

Assuming that user can filter objects by `booksCount` AND that he has four library object available:

1. with 1 book
2. with 7 books
3. with 12 books
4. with 127 books.

When user filters by amount of books and types digit X, I want to show objects with amount Y:

1. When user types 1 it should show objects with `booksCount` 1, 12, 127.
2. When user types 12 it should show objects with `booksCount` 12, 127.
3. When user types 7 it should show objects with `booksCount` 7.
4. When user types 13 it shouldn't show any objects.
5. When user type 126 it shouldn't show any objects.
6. When user types 127 it should show objects with `booksCount` 127.

Simple as that. My questions are:

1. Why this exception occurs and how can I fix it?
2. If this is a bug (please no), how can I achieve the same behaviour with this architecture?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know `DBObject` queries do not support casting numbers to strings, hence the `stringValue()` operation is currently not supported when using `querydsl-mongodb`.

Comment: Can I achieve desired behavior in some other way?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with MongoDB nor `DBObject`, only with `QueryDSL`. Hopefully one of the MongoDB folks here can help you out with that.